# SSH vulnerability detected in file cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/ssh.py

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, security, bitbucket, python-cryptography

I have written a python application that uses cryptography as one its dependencies. This application is used by another team. Since they intend to run this application on their AWS server, They'll have to package the application along with the its dependencies into a single folder and upload that folder to Bitbucket. The AWS would access this from the Bitbucket. When they are uploading the package to Bitbucket, below is the error that they are seeing. Cryptography version 3.2.1 and 4.0.0 were installed on each different occasion, but still received this error

```
{pre-receive hook declined
Push rejected due to security vulnerabilities detected by security hook.

 


@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@                                                          @
@      PUSH REJECTED DUE TO SECURITY VULNERABILITIES       @
@                                                          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

 


SSH vulnerability detected in file cryptography/hazmat/primitives/serialization/ssh.py (9f88efdfc657723baf412b1e664fa7aa1153f863) on line 52.
EC vulnerability detected in file ecdsa/keys.py (9f88efdfc657723baf412b1e664fa7aa1153f863) on line 791.
EC vulnerability detected in file ecdsa/test_keys.py (9f88efdfc657723baf412b1e664fa7aa1153f863) on line 114.
EC vulnerability detected in file ecdsa/test_keys.py (9f88efdfc657723baf412b1e664fa7aa1153f863) on line 163.
EC vulnerability detected in file ecdsa/test_keys.py (9f88efdfc657723baf412b1e664fa7aa1153f863) on line 259.
EC vulnerability detected in file ecdsa/test_pyecdsa.py (9f88efdfc657723baf412b1e664fa7aa1153f863) on line 217.
EC vulnerability detected in file ecdsa/test_pyecdsa.py (9f88efdfc657723baf412b1e664fa7aa1153f863) on line 230.
EC vulnerability detected in file ecdsa/test_pyecdsa.py (9f88efdfc657723baf412b1e664fa7aa1153f863) on line 244.
RSA vulnerability detected in file rsa/key.py (9f88efdfc657723baf412b1e664fa7aa1153f863) on line 582.
RSA vulnerability detected in file rsa/pem.py (9f88efdfc657723baf412b1e664fa7aa1153f863) on line 86.
RSA vulnerability detected in file rsa/pem.py (9f88efdfc657723baf412b1e664fa7aa1153f863) on line 113.

 

WARNING Security Validation Hook: large push detected, only scanned HEAD.
WARNING Schedule a historical scan to scan full commit history.}
```

Below are the dependencies in my application:

```
import base64
import os
import json
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from urllib.parse import urlparse,quote_plus

import jwt  # PyJWT
import urllib
import requests
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.x509 import load_pem_x509_certificate
from jose import jwt as josejwt
from jwt import ExpiredSignatureError
```

Please let me know if additional information is needed. Would really appreciate some insight on this.

P.S: The other team enabled "protected code" on their Bitbucket repository and must not uncheck it.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What is your question?

Comment: Do you have any tools published by the "other team" to check security vulnerabilities before pushing the code to bit bucket? Also, based on your question, the scan result is not showing any references about the CVEs or any other links to resolve those vulnerabilities.. usually, the vulnerabilities scanner wil report on CVEs and the links to resolve them. So the fix will be, to go through the resolution for each and every vulnerability, check if there is a fix, if so upgrade the module to fix the issues. If no fix to avail, you have to work with the "other team" on the next steps.